# Gson fails to serialize LocalDate when out of REPL?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gson

I'm writing an android Kotlin app in android studio which interacts with a firebase functions hosted api.
I decided to go with [Fuel](https://github.com/kittinunf/fuel) for the HTTP client and specifically fuel-gson for serialization.

Serialization of basic types such as Strings / Ints went well, but when I added a LocalDate to my data class, the field in the firestore database ended up as an empty map `{}`.

I tested it in a REPL and got:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson
import java.time.LocalDate

Gson().toJson(LocalDate.now())
res0: kotlin.String! = {"year":2019,"month":6,"day":20}
```

So LocalDate serialization seemed to be working just fine, but then when I tried logging it in the code with `Log.d("GSON", Gson().toJson(LocalDate.now()))`, the result again was:

`2019-06-20 23:49:26.740 12653-12653/com.utn.nutricionista D/GSON: {}`

I figured I might have messed up with my dependencies somehow so I tried the same in a clean project right after creating it and yet the result was the same.

This new project has latest android API (Q), and `com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5` as dependency.

```java
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import com.google.gson.Gson
import java.time.LocalDateTime

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d("GSON", Gson().toJson(LocalDateTime.now()))
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Any insight as to what's happening and what to do to fix this would be greatly appreciated!